# How to make menu dropdown from DDL in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

In `VBA` a ComboBox can be made to show/dropdown its list by below code.

```
ComboBox1.DropDown
```

How to make a DDL dropdown its menu like this in `AutoHotKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AHK, you have to send the control message manually using [`SendMessage`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) with a message ID of `0x014F` (which is the value of `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN`) using the following line:

```
SendMessage, 0x014F, 1, , , ahk_id %controlHwnd% ; CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F
```

To hide the dropdown, just change the `1` to a `0` like so:

```
SendMessage, 0x014F, 0, , , ahk_id %controlHwnd% ; CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F
```

This control message works on both `DropDownList` and `ComboBox` controls.

**Note:** When using `SendMessage` in AHK, it is best practice to add a comment identifying the message sent to prevent head-scratching later.

#### Explanation

Most programming languages (such as VBA) contain syntactic sugar that is out of the scope of AutoHotKey's primary focus. The line `ComboBox1.DropDown` in VBA sends a `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` control message to the control referenced by `ComboBox1`. The value in this control message is a boolean that controls whether to show (`TRUE`) or hide (`FALSE`) the drop down menu.

`CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` is an unsigned integer and its value (along with the other command messages) can be extracted from the Windows SDK. For this particular control message, it was extracted from the [`winuser.h`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/9b69fd26ac0c7d0b83d378dba01080e93349c2ed/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/WinUser.h#L11444) file as indicated on the control message reference page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cb-showdropdown#requirements).

#### Minimum Working Example

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for new scripts
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts
#SingleInstance Force ; ensures only one instance running

; AUTO-EXECUTE SECTION
; "hwndhColorChoice" stores the AHK control ID in the variable "hColorChoice"
Gui, Add, ComboBox, vColorChoice hwndhColorChoice, Red|Green|Blue|Black|White
Gui, Show
Return ; end auto-execute section


; Press F1 to show combo box options
F1::SendMessage, 0x014F, 1, , , ahk_id %hColorChoice% ; CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F

; Exit program when GUI is closed
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

#### Command References:

- [GUI Controls § DropDownList](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#DropDownList)
- [SendMessage](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm)
- [CB_SHOWDROPDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cb-showdropdown)